# compilar juego de unity con dll nativo

Tags: c#, c++, unity3d, opencv

estoy intentando montar mi **proyecto de Unity**, que he creado en **código nativo** de **C++**.

Tengo la librería en el directorio raíz del proyecto, uso dicha librería con **dllImport**.

Al compilar el programa y crear el **.exe** (ejecutable), arroja un fallo de **dllnotfoundexception**.

no sé cómo hacer para montar el programa con la **DLL**.

¿alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿Estás compilando desde Unity o desde el IDE en que generas la dll? El error dice claramente que no encuentra la dll así que el compilador o enlazador no tiene acceso a dicho archivo.

Comment: yo creo el dll que es opencv en c++ desde visual studio 2017 de 64 bits. una vez pegado en la raiz del proyecto de Unity, lo llamos con DllImport. cuando lo uso en unity me funciona perfectamente. El problema viene cuando construyo el proyecto de Unity en un .exe y me sale ese error

Comment: @UrkoSanchezOrtiz Puede ser que tu DLL dependa de otro DLL y por eso te diga que no lo encuentra?

Comment: es posible, dado que en el codigo de c++ llamo a las funciones de opencv, pero en principio si ejecuto el programa en unity funciona sin problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es exactamente una respuesta que resuelva tu problema de forma directa pero hay bastante información dentro de la documentación de OpenCV, incluso tienen un foro y un método para obtener ayuda para resolver problemas.

### Apoyo

**Cuando algo falla**
Si está intentando depurar un programa OpenCV:

- Al principio, intente solucionar el problema utilizando 
  documentación  y  tutoriales .
- Si no funciona, busque una respuesta o formule una pregunta en
  OpenCV Answers .
- Si encontró un error o desea realizar una solicitud de función,
  consulte la siguiente sección.

**Problemas de informes / características de solicitud**

- Primero, verifique el  rastreador de problemas : los errores
  conocidos, a menudo con parches o soluciones, generalmente se
  encuentran allí. Si tiene algo que agregar a un error existente,
  agréguelo como un comentario al ticket, en lugar de publicarlo en las
  listas de correo.
- Luego revise las  Respuestas de OpenCV  para ver si alguien más ha
  hecho su pregunta o ha reportado su error. Si todos los pasos
  anteriores fallaron, lo mejor que puede hacer es levantar un  boleto.
- Si no estás seguro de lo que encontraste es un error que puedes
  preguntar en  OpenCV Answers . Si el problema se confirma como un
  error, cree un ticket.

**Haciendo una pregunta**
¡Lea antes de publicar en cualquiera de los foros / listas de soporte de OpenCV!

**No haga:**

- Las siguientes no son   preguntas apropiadas:
- preguntas generales de programación / depuración
- Preguntas sobre software que no está relacionado con OpenCV
- pidiendo ayuda con tu tarea
- No  , no  en contacto con los desarrolladores / mantenedores
  directamente:
- la comunidad no puede ver las preguntas o respuestas que no se han
  hecho / contestado públicamente
- el desarrollo de código abierto funciona mejor cuando toda la
  comunidad participa en discusiones y ayuda a responder preguntas

**Hacer:**

- Sea lo más específico posible, con pasos para reproducir. Si podemos
  reproducir el problema, podemos solucionarlo rápidamente.
- Envíe todas las preguntas a  OpenCV Answers  u otra lista de correo
  correspondiente, e informe todos los errores al rastreador de
  errores.
- Especifique su plataforma (Windows 32 / 64bit, Linux x86 / x64 / ppc
  /…, MacOSX 32 / 64bit / ppc); versión del compilador; Versión /
  revisión de OpenCV; si IPP, OpenMP, MMX, SSE… se han habilitado o no,
  y cualquier otra información que nos permita reproducir el entorno,
  identificar y localizar el problema.
- Un código de ejemplo que reproduce el problema nos ayuda más. Por
  favor verifique las  muestras  - para el estilo preferido (tamaño de
  código pequeño, multiplataforma). No es  necesario  proporcionar
  ningún archivo de proyecto o archivo make, si se trata de una muestra
  corta de un solo archivo, podríamos compilarlo y ejecutarlo en un
  minuto.
- Proporcione la salida de la

  cv::getBuildInformation()

  función cada vez que informe un error sobre la versión troncal de
  OpenCV. El problema puede estar en la configuración de su
  compilación, por lo que el registro puede ayudarnos enormemente.
- Si su aplicación es compleja y el problema ocurre en algún punto
  intermedio, a menudo es posible crear una muestra independiente
  corta: captura y almacena los datos que pasas a la función usando

  `FileStorage`

  Copia la llamada de función y coloca la lectura correspondiente desde

  `FileStorage`

  delante.
- Describa exactamente lo que estaba haciendo o está tratando de hacer
  y qué salió mal. Si dice:  “¡OpenCV no funciona!”  , No podremos
  ayudarlo.
- Según corresponda, también incluya su:
- backtraces
- archivos de configuración relevantes
- Capturas de pantalla o videos para demostrar el problema.
- 
- [documentación](http://docs.opencv.org/)
- [tutoriales](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/df8/tutorial_root.html)
- [Respuestas OpenCV](http://answers.opencv.org/)
- [Respuestas de OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues)
- [Ticket](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/new)

etc...  etc...  etc... que puedes leer en los siguientes links